# How to programmatically configure L2 Hibernate caches with ECache?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, jcache

I'm trying to configure L2+QueryCache for Hibernate 6.1.7 in my Spring 6 app running Ehcache 3.10.x

In my app, Spring-level caches with method-level `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut`, `@CacheEvict`, etc. work fine. I create the caches and they work as expected.

L2 cache also works correctly, but only if **I don't create any L2 caches** and let Spring create the **default ones** (`missing_cache_strategy: create`). This is presentig heap-related problems in production because the default cache settings in Ehcache are allowing infinite heap usage.

How do I create L2 caches with my own configs, **from code**? I want to avoid the `xml` Ehcache config at this time, and Ehcache seems to be moving away from it anyway.

This is how I configure Spring-level caches, and it works:

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableCaching
    public class MyCacheConfig {
      @Bean
      public CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
          CacheManager cacheManager = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager();

         //Create a Spring-level cache
         var config = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(SomeMethodArg.class, SomeMethodReturnType.class)
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                .build();
          cacheManager.createCache("my_spr_cache", Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(config));

          return cacheManager;
      }
    }
```

Following the Ehcache docs and other sources, I was able to create L2 caches in a similar manner by adding another cache to the bean above:

```java
//Create a L2 cache
var config = CacheConfigurationBuilder
                .newCacheConfigurationBuilder(CacheKeyImplementation.class, AbstractReadWriteAccess.Item.class)
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToIdleExpiration(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
                .build();
        
//L2 cache name should be the fully qualified name of the Entity
cacheManager.createCache("com.mydomain.model.MyClass", Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(config));
```

And of course, the MyClass Entity is annotated with:

```java
@jakarta.persistence.Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) //Note that some other classes instead use NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE
```

Now the cache I made is correctly created at runtime and Ehcache doesn't build a default one. I can confirm this from the startup logs - manually created caches are logged significantly earlier on.

Now the issue: this method **is unreliable**. Firstly, it seems that changing the `ConcurrencyStrategy` breaks the cache creation code, for example, switching to `NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE` on the entity will cause Exceptions:

```java
Exception in thread "(3/16)" java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid value type, 
expected:  org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.AbstractReadWriteAccess$Item 
but was :  org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StandardCacheEntryImpl
```

The first attempt I made was obviously following the exception literally and changing the value class to `StandardCacheEntryImpl`. This just causes even more erratic behavior, with the cache behaving fine at low usage but failing when consistent load is applied:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Invalid value type, 
expected : org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.AbstractReadWriteAccess$Item 
but was : org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.AbstractReadWriteAccess$SoftLockImpl
```

If I switch those two classes back and forth, I get the same exception but reversed.

This leads me to believe that I'm using the **wrong approach** entirely. I can't find any **modern** and **updated** question on this, could someone kindly **point me in the right direction**?

---

If it can be useful, this is the relevant config in my `application.yml`:

```yaml
# [More settings here...]
  jpa:
    # [More settings here...]
    properties:
      jakarta:
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            #required - enable selective caching mode - only entities with @Cacheable annotation will use L2 cache.
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate:
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          use_query_cache: true
          region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
        jakarta:
          cache:
            missing_cache_strategy: create
```

Comment: In depth investigation reveals that when Hibernate does not find a cache for a certain name, the default caches it builds are specified at `org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory#getOrCreateCache -> createCache` which in turn makes use of an empty `javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration`. The default constructor of this class specifies `Object.class` as the value type for the cache. This is not ideal, but in absence of better answers to my question, I will resort to sticking with my approach and using Object as a value class for the cache map. It looks wrong, however.

Comment: replace `.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(CacheKeyImplementation.class, AbstractReadWriteAccess.Item.class)` with `.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Object.class, Object.class)`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov yes, I was getting to that same conclusion, see my comment above. But is this really the way? More than for it to "just work", I would like to use the proper way. This feels like a hack.

Comment: no, that is not a hack, that is how L2-cache is implemented in NBH, it does not assume the cache must be type-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cache keys `Hibernate` may potentially use three different implementations (please check `org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheKeysFactory` interface and it's `createCollectionKey`, `createEntityKey` and `createNaturalIdKey` methods), moreover, `Hibernate`, allows to override default `CacheKeysFactory`  via `hibernate.cache.keys_factory` setting, so, technically you have no chance to guess what cache key implementation will be used for particular cache region, moreover cache regions may contain different data, so, `Object.class` is a valid definition of cache key implementation.

In case of cache values implementations may also differ:

- for natural id cache `Hibernate` stores entity identifiers there
- for other caches that can be either `Map` or `StandardCacheEntryImpl` or implementation of `org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.AbstractReadWriteAccess.Lockable`

so, for cache values `Object.class` is the only valid definition as well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Since the question is more general I'll take this chance to add: did you see other issues with how I'm handling this? (That is, the bean, how I obtain the cache manager, mixing L2 cache defintion with Spring cache, the yml, etc). Comprehensive documentation of L2 cache in Spring has been very hard to find for me.

Comment: 1. caching queries [might be not a good idea](https://dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-hibernate-second-0) - in order to make it work you need to cache entities as well and [enable batch fetching](https://prasanthmathialagan.wordpress.com/2017/04/20/beware-of-hibernate-batch-fetching/).

Comment: 2. since they have removed `hibernate-ehcache` in version 6 in favour of `jcache`, it seems there are only two options to configure `ehcache`: via `xml` or via `spring`, I don't like both, moreover, I don't like the idea to configure cache via `@Cache` annotation: from my perspective the cache strategy should not depend on domain model - that is a responsibility of particular application, so we configure caches via `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` (`metadata.getEntityBindings()` > `persistentClass.setCacheRegionName/setCacheConcurrencyStrategy`) and use our own `RegionFactoryTemplate`